# CSS transition events extremely slow on IOS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-transitions

I am developing a single-page Javascript application that runs on desktop browsers and also on mobile devices via Cordova/Phonegap.

I have a slide-out menu that is implemented using CSS transitions.  I noticed that it works well on desktop browsers and android.  However, on IOS there are serious performance issues.  The transition does not appear to start on time, but once it starts the rendering and duration looks fine.  The time between starting the transition and the transitionend event is way higher on IOS than other platforms.  For example, the duration of the transition is 300ms but I'm not getting the transitionend event for 1500ms.  On all other platforms, I get the transitionend event in 325-350ms.

Transitionend Event:

- Expected: 350ms
- Actual: 1500ms

Platforms:

- Cordova 6.3.1
- Xcode 8.1 GM Seed
- IOS 10.1

Here is the CSS for the menu div.  To slide-out the menu, I add the 'open' class.  To close the menu, I remove the 'open' class.  I've tried transitioning on the 'left' property and 'transform' property, but the results are identical.

```
/* Nav Menu */

#navmenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 400px;
    z-index: 20;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    /*
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
            transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
       -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 300ms ease;
        -ms-transition:     -ms-transform 300ms ease;
         -o-transition:      -o-transform 300ms ease;
            transition:         transform 300ms ease;
    */
    left: -100%;
    -webkit-transition: left 300ms ease;
       -moz-transition: left 300ms ease;
        -ms-transition: left 300ms ease;
         -o-transition: left 300ms ease;
            transition: left 300ms ease;
}

#navmenu.open {
    /*
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
            transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 300ms ease;
       -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 300ms ease;
        -ms-transition:     -ms-transform 300ms ease;
         -o-transition:      -o-transform 300ms ease;
            transition:         transform 300ms ease;
    */
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: left 300ms ease;
       -moz-transition: left 300ms ease;
        -ms-transition: left 300ms ease;
         -o-transition: left 300ms ease;
            transition: left 300ms ease;
}
```

Question: What might be causing the delay in starting the transition, only on IOS platforms?  Are there any known solutions to circumvent the problem or speed things up?  I have other transitions in the app that take over 5s to start, making the app unusable.  I'm hoping the menu solution will apply throughout the app.  Thanks for any help or ideas you can provide.

Here is the instrumented Javascript code that I use to open/close the menu...

```
utilities.addEventListeners(navMenuButtonDiv, function () {
    var start = Date.now();
    var menuDiv = navMenu.getDiv();
    if (menuDiv.classList.contains('open')) {
        menuDiv.classList.remove('open');
    } else {
        menuDiv.classList.add('open');
    }
    var handler = function (event) {
        console.log('Transition: ' + (Date.now() - start));
        menuDiv.removeEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', handler, true);
    };
    menuDiv.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', handler, true);
 };
```

Comment: UPDATE: The latest update to IOS (10.1.1) appears to have exacerbated the problem quite considerably.  Even after porting top/left to transitioning on transforms, it is still a problem.  Any transition on iPhone5 starts very late, sometimes well more than 5 seconds after button click/touch.  Performance is somewhat better on iPhone6, leading me to believe it's a memory issue and perhaps a bit of planned obsolescence to get people off old iPhones.  Try the app on an older iPhone for a demo at https://sizzlescene.com.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When moving elements around the screen, you want to maximize performance. Instead of transitioning the `left` property, you're better off using translation. Using translation, the device will use its GPU to render the onscreen change, on a layer above the DOM. This will result in a smoother, more performant transition.

Have a look at this example. Besides using a `transform` instead of changing the `left` property, notice that I removed a bit of redundancy. You don't need to redeclare the transition on the active state.

```js
var open = document.getElementById("open"),
    close = document.getElementById("close"),
    nav = document.getElementById("navmenu");

open.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nav.classList.add("open");
}); 

close.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nav.classList.remove("open");
});
```

```css
#navmenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 400px;
  z-index: 20;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
       -o-transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
          transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#navmenu.open {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

button {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navmenu">stuff in here</div>
<button id="open">Open Menu</button>
<button id="close">Close Menu</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy Hoffman for replying.  Yes, the transition duplication in the 'open' class is not needed.  Thanks.  Your changes do work on desktop, but on mobile the click event needs to be converted to touchstart...touchend to avoid a built-in 300ms delay to allow for double-tap detection.  However, even with your changes, the delay in the start of the transition still occurs... only on IOS.  I also discovered that removing the transition and popping open the navmenu is still problematic.  So, after adding the 'open' class to the element, something is causing a delay.  Any idea how to profile?

Comment: Andy Hoffman's answer was the most helpful, although I still have some unknown activity between the time the classlist is updated and the UI changes are reflected.  Taking a look at WKWebView as an alternative to UIWebView.